# Problem while installing uwsgi on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, uwsgi

I want to install `uwsgi` in my system with Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried `pip install uwsgi`, but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Make sure that you have installed Python development packages for your operating system.

Command output:

Collecting uwsgi Downloading uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz (803 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for uwsgi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: started
Running setup.py install for uwsgi: finished with status 'error'
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install python development files, as the error tells.

Run this:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
```